# Is there always a natural "space" between cells in a table?

Tags: java, libgdx

I created a table with "buttons" aligned onto my screen for my game I am using to learn libgdx.  I want the buttons to squeeze together perfectly to form a seamless menu, however there seems to be a natural padding of 1 to 2 pixels between every cell.

Is there a way to remove that padding?

The code seems unnecessary but this is the contents of my table anyways:

```
                       table.add(buttonTyce).size(150,60).expandX().expandY().bottom().left().row();        
    table.add(buttonGrokk).size(150,60).bottom().left().row();        
    table.add(buttonCeleste).size(150,60).bottom().left().row();        
    table.add(buttonDaem).size(150,60).bottom().left().row(); 
    table.add(buttonRisp).size(150,60).bottom().left().padBottom(80).row();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't think there is default space. Are you sure that the texture you are using for your buttons doesn't contain any transparent edges? Also, there's `table.debug()` (or something like that, check the docs) to draw lines around table cells for debugging such issues.

Comment: I am using debug.  Maybe you are right and there are transparent edges on the button images.  I made my buttons as pngs in paint and then put them through 9patch.  I don't know how I would tell, though.

Comment: Doesn't 9patch use the 1 pixel border around the edges for alignment/sizing information? Try this to get a better idea what's going on with your images: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Thank you, I am probably not covering all my bases with 9patch.  I think my question can be considered answered, though I don't know how to set this as answered.

Comment: I added my comment as a real answer. Should work better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is default space. Are you sure that the texture you are using for your buttons doesn't contain any transparent edges? Also, there's table.debug() (or something like that, check the docs) to draw lines around table cells for debugging such issues.